# 'UserPasswordCredential' could not be found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, nuget-package

I am attempting to make authentication for Azure Functions in C#, Visual Studio 17. This line gives the error:

```
    var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(UserName, Password);
```

It gives the error as is if I had not included the NuGet package: "The type or namespace name "UserpasswordCredential" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or and assembly reference?)".

I have included the package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (v. 3.19.2 - latest stable). But for some reason this bit is missing (I have also tried the older versions). Microsoft themselves says it should be part of the package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.userpasswordcredential?view=azure-dotnet. But it is not.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Full code below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a new Azure Active Directory access token
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "url" > A URL for the end-point for which the access token is requested</param>
    /// <returns>The access token</returns>
    public static string GenerateActiveDirectoryAccessToken(string url)
    {
        var authority = AuthorityUrl;
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(UserName, Password);
        var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(url, ClientId, credentials);
        return authResult.Result.AccessToken;
    }
```

Comment: Did you add the `using` statement?

Comment: Yes I did: using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

Comment: It was removed. ADAL does not support that flow anymore (at least on most platforms). There are other better ways to do the authentication in a way where you don't need to hard-code passwords somewhere.

Comment: One way is to have some web front which allows a user to enable this. Then you can get a refresh token for that user, which you can then use in the function to get access tokens (and new refresh tokens).

Comment: Otherwise you might want to make authenticated calls to the function and attaching an access token to the request. Then you could use On Behalf Of to get an access token.

Answer (score 12):

Are you using .NET Core? The UserPasswordCredential is not supported in .NET Core. FYI: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/482

I also faced this issue. Hardcoding the username and the password is not a recommended way and you can use the application permissions instead of the delegated permissions. But sometimes some APIs need the delegated permissions. So I want to implement a no-user interaction method to call the Graph APIs. It looks like a deadlock.